# Injections or method call in configuration class

Tags: java, spring

In the following example is there any different between `result` and `result2` bean definitions:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public Integer data1() {
        return 42;
    }

    @Bean
    public Integer data2() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Bean
    public Integer result(
            @Qualifier("data1") Integer a,
            @Qualifier("data2") Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Bean
    public Integer result2() {
        return data1() + data2();
    }


    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        System.out.println(context.getBean("result"));
        System.out.println(context.getBean("result2"));
    }
}
```

- are there any related best practices?
- any drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

### First question: Is there any differences?

Yes, the `result` version will get two beans it depends on using dependency injection and follow all rules regarding the scopes of these beans. The `result2` version calls two factory methods itself and is not taking advantage of dependency injection.

### Second and third question: Are there any best practices or drawbacks?

The first version that actually lets spring inject the dependencies benefit from all advantages that comes with spring dependency injection. You can specify scopes and override the specifications of which beans to inject in other contexts.

The other version will just make hardcoded calls to the two factory methods itself, which means that the factory methods themselves cannot have any dependencies injected and will not respect any annotations like scope.

My recommendation is to go with version one which takes follows the dependency injection paradigm. Otherwise, at least the two factory methods should be treated as regular methods and have the spring annotations removed in order not to trick any reader of your code that spring manages the beans lifecycle.

Imagine a non-trivival example where `data1` and `data2` is creating complex beans that are used by several other beans, and where you may want to change the actual instances based on context, such as unit tests, test/stage environment or production...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote scope annotation by mistake. My question was only about parameter injection or method calls. Do you have any references that support your opinion?

Comment: No, I don't have any references to point to. Only my own experience and reasoning...

Comment: I also like the `result` option. It seems less misleading.